# How to change css styles based on element contents with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

Within the following code, I would like to hide any `li` tags that do not contain specific content. For example, hide any `li` tags that do not contain "**ALL**" or "**LOGO**" text content, as shown below.

```
<ul>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">ALL</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">GUIDES</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">LOGO</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">ICON</a></span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I know that the following css hides the `li`:

```
<li style="display:none;">
```

However, I’m hoping someone can help with the Javascript function that searches the contents of the `li`, finds the matching values, then converts `class="filterTag"` to `style="display:none;"`.

The following JS code doesn’t work for me, however, it is sourced from another example and not sure if all code is needed:

```
var listLi=document.getElementsByTagName("li").getElementsByClassName('filterTag');
for(var i=0;i<listLi.length;i++) {
    var listLink = listLi[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var j=0;i<listLink .length;i++) {
        if(listLink [j].innerHTML!==('ALL' || 'LOGO'))
            listLink [j].style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Note that I have also added the extra filter:

`.getElementsByClassName('filterTag')`
as there are other `li`'s on the page.

Note sure if I need to add the extra:

`.getElementsByTagName("a");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to separate styles in CSS instead of writing inline styles. So just add a class (in this case `fancy`, change to your needs) For illustrating purposes instead of hiding I've added a `background-color: orange;`

Please read the comments in code carefully

```js
var needles = ["ALL", "LOGO"]; // define the needles you need to find
var filterTags = document.querySelectorAll('.filterTag'); // get all filterTags
filterTags.forEach(function(filterTag){ // iterate over all filterTags
    if(needles.includes(filterTag.textContent.trim())) { // here the magic happens:
        // it compares if filterTag content is in the array of needles
        // if so we add the class name fancy 
        filterTag.classList.add('fancy');
        // instead of the above line you could do:
        // filterTag.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```css
.fancy {
    /* change the style to display none instead of background-color */
    /* display: none; */
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">ALL</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">GUIDES</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">LOGO</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">ICON</a></span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `querySelectorAll()`, `forEach()`, `querySelector()` and `includes()` like the following way:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('.filterTag');
li.forEach(function(l){
  var a = l.querySelector('a');
  if(a.textContent.includes('ALL') || a.textContent.includes('LOGO')){
    l.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">ALL</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">GUIDES</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">LOGO</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="filterTag">
        <span><a href="~">ICON</a></span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Mamun, however I noticed you used ```textContent.includes```. If we wanted to rewrite your code so that it discludes any items that doesn't match, for instance, "LOGO"? Is there a ```textContent.discludes``` option?

Comment: @RobertGodino [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) returns true or false. You could write a `discludes` function. `if(a.textContent.includes('ALL'))` is like writing `if(true == a.textContent.includes('ALL'))` so discludes is the same as `if(false == a.textContent.includes('ALL'))`

Comment: @RobertGodino, there is no such function, but you can achieve the same by prefixing the negate (`!`) operator like `!a.textContent.includes('LOGO')`:)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mamun, I used the code suggested by @caramba , as it was able to successfully query both "ALL" and "LOGO" terms.  When I added the ```(false ==``` or ```!a.textContent``` code to your script, it only selected one of the query terms. I’m sure I probably wrote the Javascript incorrectly. Thanks again